# Powershell regex replace repeating groups

Tags: regex, powershell, substitution

I have to add commas to this string: 1321654987.00 
The result should be: 1,321,654,987.00

I'm trying to use substitutions:

```
'123123897.00' -replace '^(?<start>(\d{1,3}))(?<mid>(\d{3}))*(?<end>(\.\d{2}))?$','${start},${mid}${end}'
```

But the result is following: 
1,987.00

How can I replace each matched group, not the last one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're taking the wrong approach to this. Does [.NET numeric formatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx) work better for you?

Comment: I think `$s  -replace '(?<!\..*)\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?$)', ','` will work, but Mike is right, a regex is not what you really need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex could be something like this

```
'123123897.00' -replace '(?m)(?<=[0-9])(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))', ','
```

explanation

```
# (?<=[0-9])(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))
# 
# Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Parentheses capture
# 
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=[0-9])»
#    Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))»
#    Match the regular expression below «(?:[0-9]{3})+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{3}»
#          Exactly 3 times «{3}»
#    Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?![0-9])»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
# Your regular expression may find zero-length matches
#    PowerShell allows a zero-length match at the position where the previous match ends.
#    PowerShell advances one character through the string before attempting the next match if the previous match was zero-length.
```

That being said, Mike is right that you should be using formatting functions. Following should suffice

```
"{0:N2}" -f 123123897.00
```